# Winsock - Client disconnected, closesocket loop / maximum connections

Tags: c++, client-server, winsock

I am learning Winsock and trying to create some easy programs to get to know it. I managed to create server which can handle multiple connections also manage them and client according to all tutorials, it is working how it was supposed to but :

- I tried to make loop where I check if any of clients has disconnected and if it has, I wanted to close it.
- I managed to write something which would check if socket is disconnected but it does not connect 2 or more sockets at one time

Anyone can give me reply how to make working loop checking through every client if it has disconnected and close socket ? It is all to make something like max clients connected to server at one time. Thanks in advance.

```
while (true)
{
    ConnectingSocket = accept (ListeningSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
    if (ConnectingSocket!=INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Connections[ConnectionsCounter] = ConnectingSocket;
        char *Name = new char[64];
        ZeroMemory (Name,64);
        sprintf (Name, "%i",ConnectionsCounter);
        send (Connections[ConnectionsCounter],Name,64,0);
        cout<<"New connection !\n";
        ConnectionsCounter++;
        char data;
        if (ConnectionsCounter>0)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<ConnectionsCounter;i++)
            {
                 if (recv(Connections[i],&data,1, MSG_PEEK))
                 {
                     closesocket(Connections[i]);
                     cout<<"Connection closed.\n";
                     ConnectionsCounter=ConnectionsCounter-1;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check is a socket is still open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851654/how-can-i-check-is-a-socket-is-still-open)

Comment: The example code you provided does not provide enough detail to assist. Is the provided code part of a function called in a loop? What are you seeing in the debugger?

Comment: @advent Why reject my edit of your example code? It's format is unreadable.

Comment: I didn't saw it as necessary edit. It's full code without declaring sockets, binding and listening. I will add whole loop.

Comment: May be useful to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why are you closing the socket on any error *or* on any data but *not* when you get end of stream? And what makes you think formatting code correctly is unnecessary? You're mistaken about that.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you want to manage multiple connections using a single thread. right?
Briefly socket communication has two mode, block and non-block. The default one is block mode. let's focus your code:

```
for (int i=0;i<ConnectionsCounter;i++)
{
    if (recv(Connections[i],&data,1, MSG_PEEK))
    {
        closesocket(Connections[i]);
        cout<<"Connection closed.\n";
        ConnectionsCounter=ConnectionsCounter-1;
    }
}
```

In the above code, you called the recv function. and it will block until peer has sent msg to you, or peer closed the link. So, if you have two connection now namely Connections[0] and Connections[1]. If you were recv Connections[0], at the same time, the Connections[1] has disconnected, you were not know it. because you were blocking at recv(Connections[0]). when the Connections[0] sent msg to you or it closed the socket, then loop continue, finally you checked it disconnect, even through it disconnected 10 minutes ago.

To solve it, I think you need a book **Network Programming for Microsoft Windows** . There are some method, such as one thread one socket pattern, asynchronous communication mode, non-block mode, and so on.

---

Forgot to point out the bug, pay attention here:

```
closesocket(Connectons[i]);
cout<<"Connection closed.\n";
ConnectionsCounter=ConnectionsCounter-1;
```

Let me give an example to illustrate it. now we have two Connections with index 0 and 1, and then ConnectionsCount should be 2, right? When the Connections[0] is disconnected, the ConnectionsCounter is changed from 2 to 1. and loop exit, a new client connected, you save the new client socket as   Connections[ConnectionsCounter(=1)] = ConnectingSocket;  oops, gotting an bug. because the disconnected socket's index is 0, and index 1 was used by another link. you are reusing the index 1.

why not try to use vector to save the socket.

hope it helps~

Comment: Yes, I am using single thread. I made it work out but I am missing something in this multiple connection check. Using recv is making my server be able to focus only on single client and other client has to wait till other one is closed.

Comment: This is what I thought about, I saw that class Socket has method called isDisconnected or something like that so maybe using that will be a good idea. I have still a lot to learn also I have a lot of ideas how to try implement those and other things but it will take some time for me to understand how it works and be able to work on it fluently. Thank you for your attention and good advices, it's really helpful.

Comment: Completely incorrect from start to finish. If another peer disconnected while you were checking this one, you will discover it later on when you check it. Disconnect events aren't just discarded. The only way to detect a peer disconnect is to try to read from the socket. No other socket method can possibly tell you that. Don't post misinformation here.

Comment: Is there conflict？ if the thread were waiting recv(connections[0]...) to return, while connections[1] disconnected, at this time, program did not know it, until connections[0] sent data or disconnected then loop continue to recv(connections[1]...) and got -1 returned, now we know connections[1] disconnected.  any problem?

Comment: Actually loop is working even if it's busy with other socket. If I turn off 10 clients one after other in quick time, after closing busy client I get 11 disconnect,  connect messages.