# How to check if a socket is connected or not

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am using this piece of code to send  socket command which i got from this site.

```
void SendExternalCommand(std::string Cmd,const std::string HostName,const int Port)
{

boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint   
e(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(HostName), Port);
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
socket.connect(e) ;
socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(Cmd));
socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(Cmd));
}
```

How can i check if a socket is available or not.

i tried doing  if(!socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4()))
but it does not work.

Comment: If only there were a way to find out if you're allowed to send something. Oh yes! You could try to *send* it. Sometimes it's better to seek forgiveness than ask permission :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually you should try to `recv` from the socket if you want a reliable shutdown. I don't know if boost::asio implements the shutdown, but I guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` has a `is_open()` method which seems to give the result.

However, you should be aware that between calling `is_open` and then sending data with `send`, the socket can be closed. In addition, TCP write functions usually return immediately after copying the data into the kernel buffer. If sending fails, you will get an error at the next send.

In general, it is also a good idea to read from a socket because that is the reliable way to detect a closed connection. As part of the shutdown process, a call to `recv` will return with a result of `0` when the client has closed the connection. I don't know what boost::asio implements, so it is good idea to check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `getsockopt` like this:

```
int err = 0;
socklen_t size = sizeof (err);
int check = getsockopt (socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err, &size);
if (check != 0) 
{
   //some code
}
```

Also refer: [How can I check is a socket is still open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851654/how-can-i-check-is-a-socket-is-still-open)